# args python parser, a whitespace and Spark

Tags: python, linux, apache-spark, io, redhat

I have this code in `foo.py`:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--label', dest='label', type=str, default=None, required=True, help='label')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

and when I execute:

> spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster foo.py --label 106466153-Gateway Arch

I get this error at Stdout:

```
usage: foo.py [-h] --label LABEL
foo.py: error: unrecognized arguments: Arch
```

Any idea(s) please?

---

Attempts:

1. `--label "106466153-Gateway Arch"`
2. `--label 106466153-Gateway\ Arch`
3. `--label "106466153-Gateway\ Arch"`
4. `--label="106466153-Gateway Arch"`
5. `--label 106466153-Gateway\\\ Arch`
6. `--label 106466153-Gateway\\\\\\\ Arch`

All attempts produce the same error.

---

I am using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago).

Comment: Quote it:  `launch_the_spark_script ... features.py --label "106466153-Gateway Arch"`.  Most shells that I know of will then pass the quoted stuff as a singular argument to the underlying process (`python` in this case)

Comment: Use a real working minimal example. Your code is invalid python as your `help` argument is non-terminated string.

Comment: [tag:python] would work just fine @Anthon, there is something with [tag:Spark] that interferes. Updated

Comment: If quoting doesn't work (as your edit implies), then you should provide us with how you're executing this (e.g. what shell?  What os?, etc.)

Comment: Attempts 1, 2, and 4 should be equivalent and what you want. Attempt 3 would include a literal backslash before the space that you do not want.

Comment: On progrss mgilson. @chepner agreed, but when nothing works...

Comment: What error or result *do* you get with 1, 2, or 4?

Comment: Same error @chepner. Anthon I updated with the exact code. Guys I know that it's like shooting in the dark, but you are [tag:python] giants, so please fire! :) Or upvote, so that more can see it...

Comment: @Anthon the code of my minimal example is pretty much the same as before. Anyway, I did use `nargs="+"` and now can go along with it...Posted an answer, thanks everyone for the help! :)

Comment: This looks like a bug in the cluster deploy mode submission. Reproducible on Mesos as well. One way or another nothing we solve here.

Comment: Thank you @zero323 for taking the time to reproduce and for the upvote. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a nasty workaround:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--label', dest='label', type=str, default=None, required=True, help='label', nargs="+")
args = parser.parse_args()
args = ' '.join(args.label)
print args
```

where I am using `nargs="+"` and then `join` the arguments.

I execute like this:

> spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster foo.py --label "106466153-Gateway Arch"

Also notice that this approach can work when no space exists, like this:

> spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster foo.py --label "106466153-GatewayNoSpaceArch"